# Codeigniter create zip file with existing folder and download it.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create zip with existing folder. That folder having sub folders and files.
 I am using codeigniter 2.1.4. For this i tried as below:

`$this->load->library('zip');

$this->zip->read_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cloudsip_v2/apps/feb012016/');
ob_end_clean();
$this->zip->download('feb012016.zip');`
But its downloading empty zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check permits for that folder.

Comment: its having permits 0755

Comment: try `code` $this->zip->read_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cloudsip_v2/apps/feb012016/',FALSE);

Answer (score -1):

try this ::

```
$name = 'mydata1.txt';
$data = 'A Data String!';

$this->zip->add_data($name, $data);

// Write the zip file to a folder on your server. Name it "my_backup.zip"
$this->zip->archive('/path/to/directory/my_backup.zip');

// Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

[here is link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/zip.html)